# Alertmanager cluster status is "Disabled"

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, prometheus-alertmanager

I am trying to configure alerts using Alert Manager with Prometheus (using Helm and Kubernetes). On Alert Manager UI, I am getting cluster status as disabled. How do I move it to a ready state?

[Attaching the image for the same](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KcLfv.png)

Answer (score 5):

Can you check if `--cluster.listen-address` is set to blank in your helm chart. Clustering is disabled if the mentioned key is blank.

Comment: @Prerna Singla - were you able to resolve this ? i'm getting similar issue in when i use the yamls in -> https://github.com/strimzi/strimzi-kafka-operator/blob/main/examples/metrics/prometheus-install/alert-manager.yaml

Answer (score 0):

comment the line in deployments --cluster.listen-address, Showing cluster is up after pods are restarted.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).